# Codility: PrisonEscape Solution

Tags: c++

I've recently solved **PrisonEscape** challenge on **Codility**. 
[Phosphorus](https://codility.com/programmers/challenges/phosphorus2014)

I got *33/100*. To my opinion my code was covering all of the corner cases. Unfortunately it didn't.

Let me explain my solution.

I've created a graph on an array length of N+1. I've find all the leaves and added them to a queue as a possible guard location. Then I explored through those Nodes.

I've added my ode below. I hope someone can spend their precious time to help me. Thanks.

```
#include <queue>

struct Node{
    vector<int> neighbours;
    bool hasPrisoner;
    bool guardPlaced;
    bool isVisited;
    unsigned int index;
    Node(): hasPrisoner(false), guardPlaced(false),isVisited(false),index(0)
    {
    }
};


bool shouldBeGuarded(vector<Node>& intersections, int index, int callerIndex)
{

    if(intersections[index].hasPrisoner)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(intersections[index].guardPlaced || intersections[index].isVisited)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool result = false;

    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < intersections[index].neighbours.size() && !result; ++i)
    {
        if(callerIndex ==  intersections[index].neighbours[i])
            continue;

        result = result || shouldBeGuarded(intersections, intersections[index].neighbours[i],index);
    }
    return result;
}
int solution(vector<int> &A, vector<int> &B, vector<int> &C)
{
    // write your code in C++11

    vector<Node> intersections;

    intersections.resize(A.size()+1, Node());

    for(unsigned int i=0 ; i < A.size() ; ++i)
    {
        intersections[A[i]].neighbours.push_back(B[i]);
        intersections[B[i]].neighbours.push_back(A[i]);

        if(i < C.size())
            intersections[C[i]].hasPrisoner = true;
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0 ; i < intersections.size() ; ++i)
    {
        intersections[i].index = i;
    }
    queue<Node*> guardQueue;

    for(unsigned int i=0 ; i < intersections.size() ; ++i)
    {
        if(intersections[i].neighbours.size() == 1)
        {
            if(intersections[i].hasPrisoner)
                return -1;//Prisoners can't be on exits. If they are there, now way to keep them.
            guardQueue.push(& intersections[i] );
        }
    }

    Node* guardNode = NULL;

    while(!guardQueue.empty())
    {
        guardNode = guardQueue.front();
        guardQueue.pop();
        if(guardNode->isVisited)
            continue;
        guardNode->isVisited = true;

        if(guardNode->neighbours.size() == 1)
        {
            if(intersections[guardNode->neighbours[0]].hasPrisoner)
                guardNode->guardPlaced = true;
            else
            {
                guardQueue.push(&intersections[guardNode->neighbours[0]]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            vector<int> possibleNextMoves;
            for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < guardNode->neighbours.size(); ++i)
            {
                if(intersections[guardNode->neighbours[i]].hasPrisoner)
                {
                    guardNode->guardPlaced = true;
                    break;
                }
                if(intersections[guardNode->neighbours[i]].isVisited || intersections[guardNode->neighbours[i]].guardPlaced)
                    continue;
                possibleNextMoves.push_back(guardNode->neighbours[i]);
            }

            if(!guardNode->guardPlaced && !possibleNextMoves.empty())
            {
                if(possibleNextMoves.size() == 1)
                {
                    guardQueue.push(&intersections[possibleNextMoves[0]]);
                }
                else
                {
                    vector<int> needsGuardList;

                    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < possibleNextMoves.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        if(shouldBeGuarded(intersections,possibleNextMoves[i],guardNode->index))
                            needsGuardList.push_back(possibleNextMoves[i]);
                    }

                    if(needsGuardList.size() > 1)
                    {
                        guardNode->guardPlaced = true;
                    }
                    else if(needsGuardList.size() == 1)
                        guardQueue.push(&intersections[needsGuardList[0]]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 0 ; i < intersections.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(intersections[i].guardPlaced)
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I am really interested in an optimal solution for this one, it's quite tricky if there are recombining corridors. The next challenge is so much easier.

Comment: What do you mean by recombining corridors? As I understand, the corridors was unique. Am I wrong?

Comment: No I don't think you are wrong, I took a different approach where I simplify the prison first. For me if there were loops of corridors my algorithm could be stuck. But I did not try for long as they released a new challenge.

Comment: At the beginning of the problem it say there is N corridors and N+1 intersections. This means there is no loop. If there would be loops it would never had N+1 intersections. Every loop decreases the intersection count by 1.

Comment: Ah I did not notice this, this is much easier then. Could you have an intersection that is not connected ?

Comment: Hey do you want to have a look at my solution https://github.com/BlueTrin/Phosphorus2014 , I added dot to show the graph, I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"There is a cell block near every intersection" so no you cannot have an unconnected intersection. Although the example arrays can be extended to include A[8]=89 B[8]=99, the previous N/N+1 becomes N+1/N+1+2 which violates "there is N corridors and N+1 intersections" so: no.

Much easier? How can anyone complete this task in under 2 hours? The algorithm alone cost me 4 hours.
Jules Pondart did it in 45 minutes, what kind of code god is that, i.o.w. am i a noob? Is there a java answer to the problem?

Comment: Maybe you are better than him at other things ? :)

Comment: I have added a link to my solution, I have a mistake but cannot find it, if you have some time to help a fellow candidate, I would be eternally grateful. https://github.com/BlueTrin/Phosphorus2014

Comment: Duh I made a stupid mistake in counting the # of rooms, I have 91% I don't know how to improve the performance now though